# need clarification between python's attribute access and its dir()

Tags: python, attributes, magic-methods

I have little confusion; you can see in the pic..  i have created a class, then applied `dir()` on this class to check which names are defined by this class.

Then to access attributes of this class; particularly those which startswith '`__`',  what i see is a huge list of attributes; most of them are not present in `dir()`'s list; 

so my first question is from where does they all came??
[image]

also below is my observation for which i have posted this question. it is as 
"""
`dir(object1)` gives us a list of attributes; which can be accessible on the `object2` (which is a instance of this `object1`) as `.` after that `object2` (applied that if that `object2` can become the instance of `object1`) (and with other attributes which are defined for `object2`)"""  
 **is it so??????**
 lets check them.. (i am using ipython's qtconsole)

`example 1`:
`type` is instance of itself. so lets check first for `type`. you can see the list in the snap as below; the list of `dir(type)`  and then next output of accession its attributes by placing `.` on it, (1st for those which starts with `__`) then here is a list for that(see `line 55`);

[image]

then for all remaning(its just one `mro`); so after combining both; its same as `dir(type)` 
[image]

`example 2`: lets create our own class

[image]
on `line 59`; (i.e. on instance of `testClass`) lets access first those which starts with `__` and then others as: [image]
and finally combine these two results of `line 59` is same as `dir(testClass)`. right?? Right then; lets check another example

`example 3`:
[image] and [image]
 and similarly combine the result of `line 64` and compare it with `line 54` of example 1.

 Thats it from my side. Its my observation; is this right???? i require any expert comment from python gurus on this observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dir()` shows what's in the object itself, but with the `.` operator you also can access the object's type's attributes.  Have a look at `dir(type(testClass))`, there you find the ones you were missing.

Comment: i have done "print dir(type)" , then what ever list it gave; and i compared that with placing dot on right side of "object" in my pycharm editor.. both are same. . its means dir(object) gives me the list of attributes which are available to the instance of this object????

Comment: I did not really understand your question.  But maybe this helps:  `dir()` returns the list of attribute names of the given object.  With `.` you can access these and the attributes of the type of the given object.  In your case, the given object is the class `testClass`, the type of `testClass` is `<type 'type'>` (which again also is an object).  Does this help?

Comment: I suppose your interactive program just combines dir(x) and dir(type(x)) to find all things available after the `.`.

Comment: Your comment previous to above(2nd comment from top in this answer) is right. You have already understand my question. 
But i have seen some similarity. That i have mentioned as a first comment on your answer.
And i want the confirmation of what ever i have seen(which is right in all cases..you can check them on your side also); that is as:"
`dir(object1)` gives us a list of attributes; which can be accessible on the `object2` which is a instance of this `object1` as `.` after that `object2` ". . . this is what i have seen always; does my conclusion is right???

Comment: Of course, yes.  If object2 is an instance of object1, then object1 is the type (aka class) of object2.  You are just saying the first, I'm saying the second.  Both mean the same.

Comment: `dir(obj)` shows at least `sorted(vars(obj).keys())`, which is all it shows for a module. If `obj` is a type, recursively merge in the attributes of its `__bases__`, but don't merge in `obj.__class__`. If `obj` is an instance of a type, merge in `dir(obj.__class__)`.

Comment: @eryksun: And we all can just guess what the interactive tab-expansion in Namit's editor does ...

Comment: Edit: If `obj` is an instance of a non-metaclass type (i.e. the type is not a subclass of `type`), merge in `dir(obj.__class__)`.